# Increment Database with multiple conditions

Tags: java, c#, arrays, database, increment

I'm extremely new to coding, and I need to solve a problem that I'm not sure what is the best approach. I'd appreciate enormously if anyone could point me towards a proper solution!

The problem is: I have a bunch of list of numbers (aprox. 2 thousand) each containing 6 digits, from 1 to 20, like this:

```
1 {1,13,5,16,4,19};

2 {2,5,9,15,22,8};

3 {14,23,1,13,6};

...
```

they never repeat within the same list.

I need to add new lists, that should be generated based on information from the 2k previous (I have it in an excel sheet). For example:

- The next list (6 numbers, 1 to 20), need to match a given sum (and this sum will be the most frequent sum in my database);
- They need to start with a number (for instance,1);
- They must contain at least 3 odd numbers;

I have no idea what coding language would be best to use, I'm dedicating my time learning some Python and C#, and see if I can come up with a solution, but I'm really struggling to understand whether these languages are suitable for the problem or not.

Thanks a lot in advance to anyone willing to shed some light on my problem!

Comment: Either lanugauge is more than capable of handling this problem in different ways. If you're genuinely learning, try it in both :). If you think that will take too long, try a simplified version of you problem in both first (i.e. drop the need for x odd numbers etc), then pick the one you want to build on

Comment: How are those 3 requirements _"based on information from the 2k previous"_ ?

Comment: Those are examples of requirements. They're based on previous data because the elements of one list cannot be identical to another.